# this codes below are just displaying as code in the browser, it doesn't print "hello world"

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First PHP Web Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php print('Hello World!'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

this codes above are just displaying as code in the browser, it doesn't print "hello world". Please help

Comment: where have you read that a browser can handle PHP code

Comment: Specifically in that duplicate (if you haven't solve the issue yet) pay attention to the top voted answer, which for whatever reason is buried deep in that page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/2221001